# Fastest way to read and process pdf file in c#

Tags: c#-4.0, pdf, readfile, binaryreader

I am reading pdf file into array of bytes using BinaryReader..as

```
byte[] filecontent ;
BinaryReader binReader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
binReader.BaseStream.Position = 0;
filecontent = binReader.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(binReader.BaseStream.Length));
binReader.Close();
```

Is there any alternate way to this, faster and reliable ?

Comment: How is this code slow and/or unreliable?

Comment: I am looking for alternate code, to test if it works faster than this. Or to conclude this is the only fastest way

Comment: This code is relay good. Better is not possible...